# Bidirectional communication with possibility to manage connection state - grpc

Tags: rust, websocket, connection, grpc, http2

I have client and server services on Rust.

Client should have possibility to send requests periodically to server and server vice versa.
Currently I'm using grpc(http/2) for it.

Client sends simple requests and establishes stream connection with the server, then server has possibility to send some data to the client.

But this approach seems a bit overhead, because if server sends request to the client per 1 year as example it isn't good to keep http2 stream open whole the time.

As I read info about http/2 stream I can't close and reopen it.
Maybe WebSocket will be better solution for this purposes?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't intended for architectural|design questions. In gRPC, the term "client" is used for the initiator of requests and can cause confusion with other assumptions about the terms "client" and 'server". In your case, it's possible that, what you're calling the "server" could initiate the RPC against what you're calling the "client" to send low frequency requests.